# Creating environments with different colours and sizes

Tags: color, environments

At the top of my lecture notes I define the following environments:

```
%Student copy
\newenvironment{Notes}{\LARGE\color{white}}

%My copy (uncomment out "%" below)    
%\newenvironment{Notes}{\LARGE\color{red}}
```

Throughout my lecture notes I use the `Notes` environment to comment out bits of text, equations, lists, and parts of tables. Sometimes {\Notes ...} will encompass a line, other times half a page.

However, I know this really isn't the best way of doing things as {\LARGE ..} doesn't play nicely with equations. But I'm not really sure what to do instead. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

I only need the sections to *appear* white, i.e. when I print them off. Students fill in the gaps during lectures. I noticed that when I used my solution to blank off a couple of equations at a time, the colour setting goes *odd*. By odd I mean that sections are incorrectly coloured.

Comment: Do you mean "comment out" as in prevent LaTeX from typesetting it (as if there were a comment character before each line), or as in preventing your students from seeing it?  If the latter, then the comment package is not going to do what you want [although I could be wrong; Martin's answer below seems to do that].  I suspect it's the former.  What's wrong with what you're doing now?  Are you saying that equations aren't set in the LARGE font?

Comment: The comment package is indeed not doing what you want since it won't leave gaps for the students to fill in stuff.

Comment: @Hendrik-vogt: To leave gaps, all I do is change the text colour from `red` to `white`. I just need something simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider using the [comment](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comment) package for including/excluding environments. If you just change the text color the text can still be copy/pasted which might not be what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{color}

\specialcomment{Notes}{%
  \begingroup\LARGE\color{red}}{%
  \endgroup}
%\excludecomment{Notes}

\begin{document}

Lipsum\ldots

\begin{Notes}{Note}
This is a note 
\end{Notes}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can the 'comment' package increase text size within the the notes region?

Comment: I edited the example to change both size and color of the comment.